# Java bit comparison

Tags: java, string, comparison, bit

I wrote a program that compares two Strings with bits, e.g.

IP Adress Oct1 =>
11000000

Subnetmask Oc1 =>
01000000

But the comparison of the 4th octets does not work properly.
http://pastie.org/private/xfccedpcrcksa5so6rykmg

The function is called compareBits():

```
public static String compareBits(String oct, String oct2) {
    String comparison = "";
    for(int i=0; i<=oct.length()-1; i++) {
        if(oct.charAt(i) == oct2.charAt(i) && oct.charAt(i) != 0) {
            comparison = comparison+"1";
        } else {
            comparison = comparison+"0";
        }
    }

    return comparison;
}
```

On the 4th octet it's displaying the results inversed. (00000001, but should be 10000000)

Can you help me find out where the problem of attached code I have written so far is?

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my thought of how your method compareBits should look like:

```
public static String compareBits(String oct, String oct2) {
    String comparison = "";
    for(int i=0; i<=oct.length()-1; i++) {
        if(oct.charAt(i) == oct2.charAt(i) && oct.charAt(i) != '0') {
            comparison = comparison+"1";
        } else {
            comparison = comparison+"0";
        }
    }

    return comparison;
}
```

Since you are checking the charAt(), you get a character, but you compare with 0, and not with the char literal '0'. That should do the trick.

On the other hand, I think this task could be archieved with less code, for instance:

```
long ipL = IpConverter.ipToLong(ip);
long maskL = IpConverter.ipToLong(mask);
System.out.println(IpConverter.longToIp(ipL & maskL));
```

Regards

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Could you explain me, why
oct.charAt(i) != '0' works, but
oct.charAt(i) != "02" does not?

Comment: Well, charAt(i) returns a char (primitive type), so you have to compare it with another char. The way to declare a char in Java is with simple quotes, '0' represents the character 0 (not the number 0). If you place something between double quotes ("02", for example), you are declaring a String literal which is not a primitive type but an instance of String. Objects (instances of classes) are normally compared with the equals method. However, why would you try to compare a character with "02"?